# Get image src as a ajax response

Tags: php, ajax, jquery

I need to set image src from ajax response,

I'm trying to get it from ajax but the response is coming like

```
��Y���.��L�-m1��s�%��vȪ��b<��a�����5�~$����흒6��G��H#;F9`p+��mޝ�"��t�n}FVɪ_�qd��1(��d���,���,p1q�H�D�՞�a����46V� �or9i��Y�X�OsV���{���s�K5��<����\�(��i��� etc..
```

this.

it's actually image/jpeg which is created by php file. anyone please help me to convert this to proper image source.

my ajax code is

```
$.ajax({
    method : "GET",
    url : "xxx/yyy/file.php?rand=rand()'; ?>",
    success : function(data)
    {
        $('#image_here').html('<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'+data+'">');
    }
});
```

thank you in advance.

Comment: The data you are getting from the ajax response looks like binary, not base64 like you have in your data URL.  Presumably these two need to match.

Comment: You're stating that the image data is Base64 encoded, and, well, it isn't. You will need to encode that binary data client/server side before adding to the image element.

Comment: can you please help me to encode it.

Comment: The following links should provide evrything you need to get going. Server: http://php.net/manual/en/function.base64-encode.php Client: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.btoa

Comment: If I do btoa() Im getting an error  "InvalidCharacterError: 'btoa' failed: The string to be encoded contains characters outside of the Latin1 range." like this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. I just want to do base64 encoding on image before sending it.

Thank you for all :)

Answer (score 0):

you cant use this  `url : "xxx/yyy/file.php?rand=rand()'; ?>"` coz' rand() will be same with prev value and it already faulty.

you can use Math.random();

Comment: actually my url itself inside php, like    url : "<?php echo $something/xxx/yyy/file.php?rand=rand()";?> like this... In this case rand should not be a issue I think.

Comment: discover "uniqueid" in php. save your files utf8 without bom and try again. this is encoding error.

Comment: Im using imagejpeg() in server.

Comment: you got it wrong. You must make "utf8" of ajax page encode lang.